# test data transfer tool for microsoft dynamics ax 2012 r3?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

i have a licensed version of microsoft dynamics ax 2012 r3, but i need the test data transfer tool to import data into the database. The links provided by microsoft redirect me to lifecycle services page where on registration i dont get access to the tool. If someone could be helpful and provide me a working link to download test data transfer tool. Thank you !!

Comment: Is your Microsoft account (LiveId) connected to customer account (your license) - check https://mbs2.microsoft.com/customersourceapp/myprofile/default.aspx - be sure to login with Microsoft account instead work account https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2016/02/29/which-account-use-to-login-to-lcs/

Comment: it is connected to license and still the tool is not available, my company is contacting tech support, meanwhile to accelerate work, is there any other link from where i can download the tool ? help appreciated